# In Terraria, what are the conditions to spawn a Goblin Army, and what time does it spawn?

Tags: terraria

I'm trying to get a Goblin army to spawn.  Thus far I have:

- Destroyed 1 Shadow Orb
- Have at least 200 HP currently
- and have not seen an invasion yet this game.

At what time does the Goblin Army usually spawn?  When I say time, I mean what time in the night (i.e. 12am, 1am, 2am, etc...).  Am I missing any pre-requisites to getting the army to spawn?

Comment: I don't believe you've missed any of the requirements; have you found any Goblin Scouts in the farther reaches of your world? If you have, you can just farm them to craft a [Goblin Battle Standard](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Goblin_Battle_Standard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goblin Invasions are besides the requirements randomly triggered, you could wait for a long time.

The requirements are pretty much as you already state:

- One player in the game must have 200+ current life.
- There must not have been an invasion within 7 in-game days.
- At least 1 Shadow Orb must have been destroyed.

[Source](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Army)

---

Further the wiki links to a forum discussion that states:

It triggers at the very start of day.

See [Source](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/goblin-invasion.6047/#post-111143) for the entire post

`I would love to include his C# converted source code in here as well, but the formatting goes bananas`

---

Also as  Yves wrote, you could also farm the Scouts to make a Goblin Battle Standard

Using 10 Tattered Cloth, dropped by Goblin Scouts and 5 Wood, at a Loom.

[Source](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_Battle_Standard)

Comment: I actually did notice that last night, in that it starts at the very start of day, which is 4:30AM I believe.  I noticed while I was running my server that it auto-saved right as the Goblin Army invasion warning came up.  Thanks for the tips my friend.